# Run Object.keys to include nested values in an object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, key

Say I have an object...

```
myObject = {
  prop1: 'someValue',
  prop2: {
     subProp1: 'nestedValue',
     supProp2: {
        superNestedProp: 'superNestedValue'
     }
  }
}
```

How can I run one function that will return all keys, including nested keys?

example output:

`[prop1, prop2, subProp1, subProp2, superNestedProp]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a recursive function, inside that you can make use of `flatMap` and `Object.entries` to get your expected output:

```js
const myObject = { prop1: 'someValue', prop2: { subProp1: 'nestedValue', supProp2: { superNestedProp: 'superNestedValue' } }};

const getProps = obj => Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k,v])=>typeof v=="object" ? [k,...getProps(v)] : k);

console.log(getProps(myObject));
```